# Drop rows from pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I need to drop some rows from a pandas dataframe `aa` based on a query as follows:

```
aa.loc[(aa['_merge'] == 'right_only') & (aa['Context Interpretation'] == 'Topsoil')]
```

How do I drop this selection from the datafram `aa`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do add '~'

```
out = aa.loc[~((aa['_merge'] == 'right_only') & (aa['Context Interpretation'] == 'Topsoil'))]
```

Or

```
idx = aa.index[(aa['_merge'] == 'right_only') & (aa['Context Interpretation'] == 'Topsoil')]
out = aa.drop(idx)
```

Comment: So that's what the tilde does!